# Loops within function argument of sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to add names passed from a list as plot titles to a series of boxplots using sapply but am having trouble.

First generate toy data to illustrate the problem.

```
set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(v = rep(letters[1:3], times = 4))

for (i in 1:21) { 
     x <- rnorm(12, 3, 1) 
     df <- cbind(df, x)
     }

colnames (df)<- c("group", paste(rep(letters[1:7], each = 3), rep(1:3,  times = 7), sep = ""))
```

This gives us a dataset with columns clustered by first letter of column name. This is analogous to my own dataset where there is one questionnaire with multiple items measured at several time points (a LOT of time points). This questionnaire yields  several factor scores. So there are a several clusters of columns that represent each factor of the questionnaire measured several times. In this toy dataset we could think of the letter in the column name as indicating which factor, and the number indicating which time point.

I want to be able to choose which cluster/factor I make boxplots of via an sapply function. So I need to make a list whose components are each cluster of column names.

```
colsList <-list (aCols <- c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
                 bCols <- c("b1", "b2", "b3"),
                 cCols <- c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
                 dCols <- paste("d", 1:3, sep = ""),
                 eCols <- paste("e", 1:3, sep = ""),
                 fCols <- paste("f", 1:3, sep = ""),
                 gCols <- paste("g", 1:3, sep = ""))
```

Now to make a boxplot function. I want to make plots for each cluster factor according to group.

```
boxplotFunct <- function (DV, IV, Title) {
                 boxplot(DV ~ IV, main = Title, horizontal = TRUE)
}
```

Now to call the function in an sapply loop.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))

sapply(df[,colsList[[1]]], function(x) boxplotFunct(x, df$group, colsList[[1]]))
```

The boxplots work but the title for each boxplot contains all three column names instead of the corresponding column name. How would I do this while still using sapply?

I would welcome suggestions how to do this whole procedure better, but I'd mainly like some advice on how to solve my particular problem: to include another loop within the sapply loop as it were (i.e. this is more for my general learning about the apply family than how to draw a graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sapply` code can be considerably reduced when iterating over `colsList[[1]]` rather than `df[, colsList[[1]]]`.

```
sapply(colsList[[1]], function(x) {
  boxplotFunct(df[, x], df$group, x)
})
```

[image: boxplots]

---

**Update:**

In response to the below comment, let us assume you would like to replace the existing figure titles with strings from another list. I tend to use `foreach` for such tasks which behaves very similar to `sapply`, but allows you to specify multiple input lists. Have a look at [Using The `foreach` Pakage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf) if you are not familiar with the package yet. Here is some sample code.

```
## alternate column names
colsList2 <- list(hCols <- paste("h", 1:3, sep = ""),
                  iCols <- paste("i", 1:3, sep = ""),
                  jCols <- paste("j", 1:3, sep = ""),
                  kCols <- paste("k", 1:3, sep = ""),
                  lCols <- paste("l", 1:3, sep = ""),
                  mCols <- paste("m", 1:3, sep = ""),
                  nCols <- paste("n", 1:3, sep = ""))

## create plots
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))

library(foreach)
foreach(x = colsList[[1]], y = colsList2[[1]]) %do%
  boxplotFunct(df[, x], df$group, y)
```

[image: boxplots2]

Comment: Thanks @fdetsch. Very elegant. This has actual been most illuminating.

Comment: What if I wanted to label the graphs with a different name than the column name, and I wanted to call these column names from a second list? say for the sake of argument the same sort of schema for labels as colsList but running from h to n.

Comment: @llewmills, I updated the above code in response to your latest comment.

Comment: fantastic! Thank you so much @fdetsch

Comment: @llewmills, then you should probably accept the answer to signal that the question is closed ;-)

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. Still a relative novice at all this. Thanks again for your help. I sense this will be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
sapply(seq(lengths(colsList)[[1]]), function(x) 
  boxplotFunct(df[,colsList[[1]][x] ], df$group, colsList[[1]][x]))
```

i.e. use an index.

Comment: Yep. Perfect. Thanks @lukeA.

Comment: I don't suppose you could deconstruct it for me? I get the x index i think but I don't understand what you did with the first argument (i.e. what function do 'seq' and 'lengths' serve?)

Comment: Sure. `lengths(colsList)` gives you a vector with the lengths of each vector in your list (they are all of length 3). `lengths(colsList)[1]` or `length(colsList[[1]])` gives you the length of the 1st vector in your list. And `seq(3)` or `seq_len(3)` generates an integer sequence from 1 to 3. You could also do `seq_along(colsList[[1]])` or just `1:3` --> many ways to archieve your goal. Also note that `?lengths` etc give you a help on a function.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of lengths.